# Obtaining BreezeJS Predicate equivalent on the Server Side

Tags: linq, entity-framework, breeze

There are times when I wish to execute the same query on the server as I do on the client when using the BreezeJS library.

Here's a trivial example. Imagine the results of a query are limited on the client for paging using skip() and take(). An "Export" function would allow the download of the unpaged dataset; ie: without the "take/skip" restrictions.

Now in a simple "Select * from TableName" type of query, this is trivial, but what if the breeze Predicate is complex, and dynamically created (precluding using a well-known server side SQL View).

Ideally, I'd like to know the source code that the Breeze.js .NET client uses to translate the Predicate into a Linq Where clause.

---

This isn't my best question I've ever posted, so if you're willing to help, and need more info, please comment and I'll be happy to post an example or more details.

Comment: Don't understand the question at all. There is no such thing as a "Breeze.js .NET client". The source code is on GitHub but I rather doubt that is really what you want. Do you want to write a single breeze.js query that can either target the server or target the local cache? That can be a simple as adding `.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache)` to your query.

Comment: My goal is to have a function which can be passed into a Linq .Where(thatFunctionhere) method which would be equivalent of the Breeze.js's .where(predicate). 

When an arbitrary event occurs on the server, I wish the server to be able to determine if the Entities involved pass the client side .where().  

Ultimately, I wish to create a client side object which extends EntityQuery, with a "register" method. This method signals the server that the client is interested in updates which apply to the query's result set. This would allow the creation of a "live query".

Comment: Conceptually, I'm trying to achieve the same behavior as Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/).  All the parts are in place for this, minus some method to signal the client's side interest in particular entities (the ones that match the .where() clause.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `[BreezeController]` attribute for the Web API. You'll see there how it composes a LINQ expression that includes the client query parameters.

However, I suspect for your purposes it would be more useful to have the client query information in a parsed form so that you can set up an appropriate server-side data watcher and use it to filter for changes of interest to a client. The Web API gives you this information in the optional parameter, `ODataQueryOptions<T> options` where `T` is the same type as in the `IQueryable<T>`.

In theory you could send your query to a "resource" that is actually just a method that registers for changes of interest

For example, suppose you had a query for hot products

```
var hotStuff = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Products').where('IsHot', 'eq', 'true');
manager.executeQuery(hotStuff).then(success, fail);
```

You revise that query slightly by *targeting a different resource*

```
var hotStuffWatcher = breeze.EntityQuery.from('ProductsWatch').where('IsHot', 'eq', 'true');
manager.executeQuery(hotStuffWatcher); // you don't care what or whether it returns
```

On the Web API side, that method is

```
[HttpGet]
[BreezeQueryable] // Must tell breeze to treat this method as if it returned IQueryable<T>
public RegistrationToken ProductsWatch(ODataQueryOptions<Product> options)
{
    var registrationToken = Watch<Product>(options);
    return registrationToken; // perhaps useful when client wants to cancel the watch
}
```

Please understand that I'm mostly speculating to give you an avenue for your research.

Comment: Actually, you're spot on what I'm angling for.  Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction! 

I'll post a proof of concept once I get this up and running.

Comment: Sweet! Looks like I can take the resulting object and store it, and call options.ApplyTo(_contextProvider.Context.{EntitySource}) or similar to achieve what I was looking for.

Again, thanks for this. I'll try to contribute something back to the community once I get it working for my purposes.